# Java based embedded database to store an append-only list

Tags: embedded-database

Looking for a Java based embedded db that can be used to store an append-only list. Specifically:

1. I don't have any keys. I just have an ordered list of strings.
2. The list is append-only
3. I won't be accessing elements randomly from this list. I will only be iterating in sequence starting from beginning and going till end
4. I need transactions. Thus, I need to be able to abort inserts if need be.
5. I want to be able to delete the entire list
6. I don't know the size of the list in advance. Thus any database that requires me to declare maximum # of elements in the list is ruled out.
7. Java API
8. Needless to say the library should support incremental saving i.e., it shouldn't be saving the entire collection everytime I add an element to the list.
9. I need durability. When `list.append(item)` returns, we can be confident that the `item` has been persisted to the database.

Code sample appreciated with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Xodus https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus might fit your requirements.  The underlying database is supports transactions, is append only, and schmealess.  A key-value structure in Xodus might fulfill your needs, as you could make an accessor that allows only appended, committed values.  Otherwise your sorta describing a block-chain.